# Обработка входящего параметра в Jasperreports

Tags: java, jasperreports, jasperstudio

В сложном отчете, в котором существует два разных запроса для основного отчета и вложенной таблицы требуются два входящих параметра из Java кода. Но приложение может выдать только один параметр (менять нельзя). Вопрос:  можно ли передать передать параметр одной строкой с разделителем (например "%"), и уже средствами Jasper Studio распарсить?  Если можно, то как реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я помню, в шаблонах `jasper reports` есть возможность вызывать методы для объектов. Тогда можно сделать простой `split("%")` и взять необходимый элемент из массива:

```
($P{name_parameter}.contains("%") ? $P{name_parameter}.split("%")[1] : "unknown")
```

более подробно про выражения в шаблонах написано в [документации](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/expressions)

Comment: Артем, спасибо.  Сразу следующий вопрос, как присвоить двум параметрам значения до и после разделителя?  $P{name_parameter1}.split("%")[0]  и $P{name_parameter2}.split("%")[1] ?

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш вопрос, в момент генерации шаблона вы передаете значение переменной в него, т.е. допустим "hello%world". В шаблоне уже в нужных местах просто делаете проверку на присутствие `%` в строке, затем разбиваете его на массив, и достаете соотвествующий элемент до разделительного символа `%` это [0] после это [1]

Comment: В момент генерации шаблона передается переменная "hello%world". В шаблоне разбиваю на массив "hello" и "world". Вопрос, для приема этой переменной используется параметр. В тоже время в самом шаблоне нужно задействовать еще два параметра, один со значением "hello" для основного отчета, и второй со значением  "world" для вложенной таблицы. Нужно ли создавать три параметра, или можно уменьшить их количество?  Не будет ли проблем с неиспользуемым после парсинга параметром?

Comment: Честно сказать, я давно работал с jasper reports и не могу точно сказать как  это сделать, но мне кажется что можно обойтись и без заведения переменных для данных значений